# Solve for three distinct digits A,B,C - no programming please

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, number-theory

$A$, $B$ and $C$ are three distinct digits between 1 and 9 (not 0).

What are they if:

1. $A + B^2 + C^3 = ABC$ (need three solutions)
2. $A + B^2 + C^3 = BAC$ (one solution)
3. $A + B^2 + C^3 = ACB$ (one solution)

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SHOUT.

Comment: This seems like exactly the sort of question that writing a program is the *right* way to solve.

Comment: Did you find this puzzle somewhere else, or did you make it up yourself? If you found it, please [edit] to include a link to your source.

Comment: There are actually four solutions to _A+B²+C³ = ABC_, but I'm afraid I used a computer to find them...

Comment: I found this myself. But puzzles like these are out there I am sure. There is  logic one can use to narrow the choices down

Comment: I didn't realize there were 4 solutions. I got 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.

> A = 1, B = 3, C = 5 -> 135
>  A = 1, B = 7, C = 5 -> 175
>  A = 5, B = 1, C = 8 -> 518
>  A = 5, B = 9, C = 8 -> 598
>
>  By simple math, we can assume right away that C cannot be 1,2,3,4 and that A cannot be 8 or 9.
>  We know that the number must end in C so lets find combinations that do so.
>  C = 5 -> 12**5**
>  C = 6 -> 21**6**
>  C = 7 -> 34**3**
>  C = 8 -> 51**2**
>  C = 9 -> 72**9**
>  Note : A cannot be 6 either.
>  12**5** + 0 = XX**5**
>  21**6** + 0 = XX**6**
>  34**3** + 4 = XX**7**
>  51**2** + 6 = XX**8**
>  72**9** + 0 = XX**9**
>  The probability that A+B must end in 0 is pretty high so lets start with that.
>  A = 1, B = 1 -> 2
>  A = 1, B = 2 -> 5
>  A = 1, B = 3 -> 10
>  A = 1, B = 4 -> 17
>  A = 1, B = 5 -> 26
>  A = 1, B = 6 -> 37
>  A = 1, B = 7 -> 50
>  A = 1, B = 8 -> 65
>  A = 1, B = 9 -> 82
>  From the list up there, we can just do +1 on each of them to find the result for every possible A so...
>  A = 1, B = 3 -> 10
>  A = 4, B = 6 -> 40
>  These are the only 2 combinations that can end in 0 and use allowed numbers. Lets try combining it with C = 5,6 and 9.
>  A = 1, B = 3, C = 5 -> 135 (Yay! got 1!)
>  A = 1, B = 3, C = 6 -> 226
>  A = 1, B = 3, C = 9 -> 739
>  A = 1, B = 7, C = 5 -> 175 (Yay! another 1!)
>  A = 1, B = 7, C = 6 -> 266
>  A = 1, B = 7, C = 9 -> 779
>  A = 4, B = 6, C = 5 -> 165
>  A = 4, B = 6, C = 6 -> 6 is not distinct
>  A = 4, B = 6, C = 9 -> 769
>
>  Next are combinations ending in 4
>  A = 3, B = 1 -> 4
>  A = 5, B = 3 -> 14
>  A = 8, B = 4 -> 24
>  A = 9, B = 5 -> 34
>  A = 8, B = 6 -> 44
>  A = 5, B = 7 -> 54
>  A = 3, B = 9 -> 84
>  Now we try those for C = 7.
>  A = 3, B = 1, C = 7 -> 347
>  A = 5, B = 3, C = 7 -> 357
>  A = 8, B = 4, C = 7 -> 367
>  A = 9, B = 5, C = 7 -> 377
>  A = 8, B = 6, C = 7 -> 387
>  A = 5, B = 7, C = 7 -> 7 is not distinct
>  A = 3, B = 9, C = 7 -> 427
>
>  Next are combinations ending in 6
>  A = 5, B = 1 -> 6
>  A = 7, B = 3 -> 16
>  A = 1, B = 5 -> 26
>  A = 5, B = 9 -> 86
>  Now we try those for C = 8.
>  A = 5, B = 1, C = 8 -> 518 (Yay another 1!)
>  A = 7, B = 3, C = 8 -> 528
>  A = 1, B = 5, C = 8 -> 538
>  A = 5, B = 9, C = 8 -> 598 (Yay another 1!)

2.

> Since the second one also ends by C, the previous data can all be reused.
>  By looking carefully at my attempts for numbers ending in 4, I found this solution.
>  A = 5, B = 3, C = 7 -> 357

3.

> A = 2, C = 6, B = 7 -> 267
>  By simple math, we can assume right away that C cannot be 1,2,3,4 and that A cannot be 6, 8 or 9(same as before).
>  We know that the number must end in **B** so lets find combinations that do so.
>  B = 1 -> **1**
>  B = 2 -> **4**
>  B = 3 -> **9**
>  B = 4 -> 1**6**
>  B = 5 -> 2**5**
>  B = 6 -> 3**6**
>  B = 7 -> 4**9**
>  B = 8 -> 6**4**
>
>  **1** + 0 = XX**1**
>  **4** + 8 = XX**2**
>  **9** + 4 = XX**3**
>  1**6** + 8 = XX**4**
>  2**5** + 0 = XX**5**
>  3**6** + 0 = XX**6**
>  4**9** + 8 = XX**7**
>  6**4** + 4 = XX**8**
>  8**1** + 8 = XX**9**
>
>  The probability that a number that ends in 8 is the correct answer is the most likely, so lets start with that.
>  List of AC combinations that adds up to **8**.
>  A = 1, C = 5 -> 126
>  A = 1, C = 6 -> 217
>  A = 1, C = 7 -> 344
>  A = 1, C = 8 -> 513
>  A = 1, C = 9 -> 730
>  From the list up there, we can just do +1 on each of them to find the result for every possible A so...
>  A = 3, C = 5 -> 128
>  A = 2, C = 6 -> 218
>  A = 5, C = 7 -> 348
>  A = 6, C = 8 -> 518
>
>  Now we try those for B = 2, 4, 7 or 9.
>  A = 3, C = 5, B = 2 -> 132
>  A = 3, C = 5, B = 4 -> 144
>  A = 3, C = 5, B = 7 -> 177
>  A = 3, C = 5, B = 9 -> 209
>
>  A = 2, C = 6, B = 2 -> 222
>  A = 2, C = 6, B = 4 -> 234
>  A = 2, C = 6, B = 7 -> 267 (Found you!!!)
>  A = 2, C = 6, B = 9 -> 299

Comment: Wow. Kudos Stack Reader. Did you get 267 also?

Comment: @DeepakMahulikar No, since it doesn't end in C, I would have had to redo a lot of the math but I had no more time.

Comment: @DeepakMahulikar Ok, I just finished it.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. $A+B^2+C^3=ABC$
>
>    - $135$
>
>      $175$
>
>      $518$
>
>      $598$
>
>    $A+B^2+C^3=BAC$
>
>    - $357$
>
>    $A+B^2+C^3=ACB$
>
>    - $267$

Alas, I did this by hand, brute force. 
(So, the secret is out — I have no life.) 
But it was *guided* brute force.

> I constructed these tables:
> \begin{array}{c|ccccccccc c|cccccccc}n^2&1^2&2^2&3^2&4^2&5^2&6^2&7^2&8^2&9^2&\quad n^3&1^3&2^3&3^3&4^3&5^3&6^3&7^3&8^3&9^3\\+&1&4&9&16&25&36&49&64&81&\quad+&1&8&27&64&125&216&343&512&729\\\hline1&*&5&10&17&26&37&50&65&82&\quad&*&9&28&65&126&217&344&513&730\\2&3&*&11&18&27&38&51&66&83&\quad&3&*&29&66&127&218&345&514&731\\3&4&7&*&19&28&39&52&67&84&\quad&4&11&*&67&128&219&346&515&732\\4&5&8&13&*&29&40&53&68&85&\quad&5&12&31&*&129&220&347&516&733\\5&6&9&14&21&*&41&54&69&86&\quad&6&13&32&69&*&221&348&517&734\\6&7&10&15&22&31&*&55&70&87&\quad&7&14&33&70&131&*&349&518&735\\7&8&11&16&23&32&43&*&71&88&\quad&8&15&34&71&132&223&*&519&736\\8&9&12&17&24&33&44&57&*&89&\quad&9&16&35&72&133&224&351&*&737\\9&10&13&18&25&34&45&58&73&*&\quad&10&17&36&73&134&225&352&521&*\end{array}
> Then, to solve $A+B^2+C^3=ABC$,
> I looked at each possible value of $C$
> (the least significant digit of $ABC$). 
> If $C=1$, $4$, $5$, $6$ or $9$,
> then $C^3 \equiv C \pmod {10}$,
> so I needed to look only at $A$ and $B$ values
> where $A+B^2\equiv 0\pmod {10}$. 
> Similarly, if $C=2$ or $7$,
> then $C^3 \equiv C-4\pmod {10}$,
> and I needed to look only at $A$ and $B$ values
> where $A+B^2\equiv 4\pmod {10}$.
> That left only a few dozen combinations to look at,
> rather than $504~~(9\times 8\times7)$.

Comment: Great. But logically you can eliminate a few numbers quickly (see answers by Stack reader)